# space after list item

Tags: css

I'm trying normalize the gap between when the bullet ends and the text begins across browsers. Currently there is a huge GAP after the bullet. Please note I'm not looking at the gap between list items, but the gap between the list item bullet and the text.

1. <--- This gap here
2. List Item
3. List item

Answer (score 2):

The [text-indent](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent/) CSS property is used to specify how much horizontal space text should be moved before the beginning of the first line of the text content of an element.

```css
li {
  text-indent: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thanks, but that did nothing in either IE or Chrome. I also tried with OL and UL as well.